# debug Silverlight project to an ASP.NET solution

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, debugging

I canNOT do it (debug Silverlight project to an ASP.NET solution), I have followed suggestion from this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/68127/Unable-to-DEBUG-Silverlight-project.aspx

But without much luck.

I have to manually go in and attach to process the silverlight page.

All suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

Voodoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have this in your ASP.NET's web.config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: It doesn't allow me to have targetFramework attribute in mine. I do however have "<compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" />" - If I set the Silverlight test page as the startup then the debugger loads symbols but not if I am coming from a different aspx page, I hope this makes sense..

Comment: If you are not loading the page from directly in VS than I don't think VS will load the symbols on it's own.  If you are getting there through a link you will I believe you have to attach separately.

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks, try this, if you've not already done so:

1. Right-click -> Properties on the web project.
2. At the very bottom in one of the tab menus, there is an option to toggle debugging. One of these checkboxes is for Silverlight. Enable it.
3. Run in debug mode and see if break point hits.

good luck with that.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this already. That's what the link in my question suggested as well....I am going to update my question later to give more info on it. I know that the new xap files is being used when I debug, the debugger just doesn't break into it and I have to manually attach the process.

Comment: I noticed today that i couldnt debug using Firefox. But in IE8 i could. I haven't checked yet, but im wondering if it's because of the browser's 'debug script' settings. Worth a try.